# ImageViewTouch doesn't work with older phones (GestureDetector)

Tags: android, imageview, gesture, gestures, gesturedetector

I have a problem with [ImageViewTouch (ImageViewZoom)](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom/tree/master/ImageViewTouch).

Especially with this line in ImageViewTouch class:

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector( getContext(), mGestureListener, null, true );
```

Everything works fine when there is a GestureListener available on the phone.
When there is not there are some errors.

I've tried to repair it by changing this line into:

```
try {
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector( getContext(), mGestureListener, null, true );
}
catch(Exception e1) {
    try {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector( getContext(), mGestureListener )
    }
    catch(Exception e2) {
        System.out.println("No gesture detector.");
    }
}
```

I've also changed this line:

```
if ( !mScaleDetector.isInProgress() ) mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent( event );
```

into this:

```
if ( ( !mScaleDetector.isInProgress() ) && ( mGestureDetector != null ) ) mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent( event );
```

From my point of view this change shouldn't have any effect on phones, which everything worked well before on. But now on my own phone (on previous version everything worked fine) I am not able to use double tap zoom.

Do you have any idea why it works that way?
How can I make it works even on older phones?